# Use page id in wp nav menu li a

Tags: wordpress

I make a wordpress menu in my wordpress theme. I want to make it a one-page theme i.e. If the theme have Home,Services,Our Team,Work,Contracts menu.

I want to make such that If i click on services. The page will go services area of the same page. I know that in HTML Template this is done using id of that area i.e `<li><a href="#service">Services</a></li>`.

But I want to use it in wordpress theme. But I don't know how I can use it.

The menu dynamic code of my header php is below.

```
<div class="header_menu">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu', 'menu_id' => 'nav' ) ); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've tried to use an anchor?

You have 2 solution at this problem:

1) Manage your wp menu to create custom link with anchor;

2) Try to use jQuery to modify structure of menu, after page loading.

Comment: I want use specific area id in my theme main menu anchor. When I will click on that menu anchor the anchor will go me on the specific id area.

When I use specific menu dynamic code in my header.php page. But I can not understand how i put my text area id in specific menu so that when I click the menu, the will go me the specific id